# Decomposition of Bounded Variation Functions

Tags: real-analysis, bounded-variation

I know that if $f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ is a function of bounded variation, I can write it as:
$$
f(x)=\frac{S(x)+f(x)}{2}-\frac{S(x)-f(x)}{2}
$$
where $S(x)$ is $f$'s variation on $[0,x]$, so it is a decomposition of $f$ into two positive monotonoe functions. I read somewhere (And I am truly sorry but I can't remember where) that this composition is minimal in the sense that if I have $f(x)=g(x)-h(x)$ where $g,h$ are positive and monotone, that $\frac{S(x)+f(x)}{2}\leq g(x),\frac{S(x)-f(x)}{2}\leq h(x)$. I was having trouble of proving that last part, and it seems quite simple.

Obviously I tried to write the equations as:
$$
\frac{S(x)+f(x)}{2}-\frac{S(x)-f(x)}{2}=g(x)-h(x) \\
\Longrightarrow g(x)-\frac{S(x)+f(x)}{2}=\frac{S(x)-f(x)}{2}-h(x)
$$
But even the monotonicity doesn't appear to be useful here.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: show by the definition of $S$ with partitions and the triangle inequality that if $f=g-h, g,h \ge 0$, monotonic, then $S \le g+h$ and you are done

Comment: Somewhere in your proof it will be necessary to actually use the fact that $S(x)$ is the total variation of $f$ on the interval $[0,x].$ Have you thought about how to do that? $\qquad$

Comment: If you can show that $\frac{S(x)+f(x)} 2 \le g(x), \vphantom{\dfrac 1 {\displaystyle\sum}}$ then from the last inequality in your question you immediately get $\frac{S(x)-f(x)} 2 \le h(x).$ So just establishing the first inequality in this comment will give you everything. $\qquad$

Comment: I will give it a try, didn't actually consider using the total variation definition here. Thank you!

Comment: The total variation of $f$ on $[0,x]$ is the least upper bound of the set of all values of a certain function whose domain is the set of all partitions of the interval $[0,x].$ Now notice that this characterization starts with the word "least". It's the smallest of all possible upper bounds, and you're trying to prove that $S(x)$ is the smallest of all possible members of another set of numbers. Might those two sets be the same, or otherwise have the same smallest member?